# Unresolved external symbol error while trying to compile caffemodel parser

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

Trying to run this code - https://github.com/Smorodov/Caffemodel-Parser
Steps I followed - 
1) Copy contents of protobuf 3.3 to protobuf folder
2) Copy gmock contents to protobuf folder
3) Run CMake
4) Run generate_caffe_pb_cc.bat file
5) Build project

getting this error

4>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::default_recursion_limit_" (?default_recursion_limit_@CodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@0HA)

4>caffe.pb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class google::protobuf::internal::ExplicitlyConstructed,class std::allocator > > google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string" (?fixed_address_empty_string@internal@protobuf@google@@3V?$ExplicitlyConstructed@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@123@A)

What am  I doing wrong?

Using VS 2010

Comment: Did you check the generated project linker properties? Do the paths to protobuf correspond with its location?

Comment: Yes they were same